# How to use 2 serial ports on the same RaspberryPI?

Tags: serial, uart

In my case we need to connect two devices with raspberry pi using UART but I found only one RX/TX GPIOs (14,15) but we need another one.

I don't know if I can usb port as UART ?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use a USB serial dongle as a UART. They usually show up as /dev/ttyUSB0.